# How to play Music Files that has image?

Tags: c#

I am making music player, and this program occurred a problem.

This is how I play music player.

```
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand, StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);

    OpenFileDialog openMusic = new OpenFileDialog();
    private void PlayPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openMusic.Title = "openMusic";
        openMusic.Filter = "music files (*.mp3, *.wav, *.flac)|*.mp3;*.wav;*.flac";
        openMusic.RestoreDirectory = true;

        mciSendString("open \"" + targetMusic + "\" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        Stop.Enabled = true;

        if (PlayPause.Text.Equals("▶"))
        {
            mciSendString("play MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            PlayPause.Text = "||";
        }
        else
        {
            mciSendString("pause MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            PlayPause.Text = "▶";
        }
    }
```

It exactly works. But, If I play a music file that has album image, It doesn't work. This program cannot play that kind of music file, but music file that doesn't have album image.

So, I saw that music file with HxD, and there is a image file in music file.
I think That image must be extracted.

If my thought is right, can you tell me how to do this?

If my thought is not right, what I should do?

Comment: What is the music file name and extension?

Comment: It's mp3 file and its name is '01. 序曲 -overture-.mp3'.